# Arduino crash after 6 hours

Tags: c, arduino

I wrote an Arduino [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) for [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) Rev3 to monitor temperature and electrical current. My Arduino 'crashes' after 6+ hours.

After resetting the Arduino, it runs well again. Did I write something that cause this problem in my code?

## Code, at pastebin

http://pastebin.com/1G8SwHge

Comment: What does 'crash' mean? You must provide more details, and better yet, debug your application and pin-point the line that's causing the error.

Comment: @Jesse, he is for sure talking about an hardware crash of the Arduino. Once it crash you cannot debug it.

Comment: Has this happened multiple times?

Comment: @Jesse It just stack when crash happen couldn't access (Im using raspberry I2c).

Comment: @FeliceM I got this post to check my variables: http://www.designer2k2.at/home/arduino/49-arduino-ram-overflow.html. I got this: 
text data bss dec hex filename 
8784 58 756 9598 257e C:\Users\ganuwame\AppData\Local\Temp\build6748804578659212664.tmp\latest_1.cpp.e‌​lf. summ data and bss 814 < 2k. Base on that post It seem no problem with the variables, isn't It?

Comment: @Dancrumb Yes, and run again after reset it.

Comment: @Nugraha, are you using am EmonTX associated with your Arduino? What you do with the acquired data, do you store them somewhere or just display?

Comment: @Nugraha However, if you are working with external sensors and shields may also happen that he fault is external to the Arduino. In these cases sometimes is convenient to use a watchdog which resets the Arduino on its own and then the problem is clear out. If you do not come right with the software have a look here: http://tushev.org/electronics/arduino/item/46-arduino-and-watchdog-timer

Comment: Because you are new here, do not forget to mark as accepted the answer that satisfy your question. We have thousands of unanswerd questions only because people forget to to it.

Comment: @FeliceM Actually, I don't use any shields being attached with the Arduino. I directly connect the CT sensor http://www.yhdc.com/english/productshow.asp?id=191 and DHT22 http://www.adafruit.com/products/385 to analog pin on the Arduino. I send the acquired data to Raspberry Pi by I2C, and display it in a web Apps. I dont store any data in arduino.

Comment: @FeliceM I am sorry. I'm doing experiments to the solutions you gave to me. I'm observing the stability of each solution, still do it. I need the time to know which solution affect to this problem. I sure that I will not forget the answered mark :). I really appreciate to you all, that have been paying attention to my question. Thanks to you All.

Comment: @FeliceM I'm trying to see the watchdog timer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one thing, you're overflowing your string buffers.

You've assigned 15 bytes for `cc`

```
char cc[15];
```

But you have code:

```
strncat(cc,o,20);  
strncat(cc,"|",20);
strncat(cc,m,20);  
strncat(cc,"|",20);
strncat(cc,n,20);
```

That could put up to 62 bytes in there. The same is true for most of your other buffers.

In addition, you're using multiple 3rd party libraries. Any one of those could contain a memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably you run out of [SRAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_random-access_memory) memory. Try to outcomment some variables and run it again to check if that is the problem. You have a lot of variables and that could be the problem having only 2 KB of SRAM on Arduino Uno.

Comment: Running out of memory would only be the cause after 6 hours if there is a memory leak, not because of the number of variables.

Comment: @Dancrumb, exactly what I was trying to say. Thanks!